# Can I query by document id with full text search on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

After creating a document with a explicit id like this:

```
Document(doc_id = 123)
```

Is it possible to find that document using the id, similar to `get_by_id` with the Datastore?

I've tried queries with `id:123`, `_id:123`, `doc_id:123`, and `_doc_id:123`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Index.list_documents` has the options `start_doc_id` and `limit` which can be used to get a single document by id.

```
documents = index.list_documents(start_doc_id = id, limit = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I also found in Java that you can do index.get(ID), which might be useful for Java users.

Here's the Javadoc:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/search/Index#get(java.lang.String)